# flask-graphql unable to detect schema

Tags: python, flask, graphql, graphene-python

I'm trying to use flask_graphql the following way:

```
app.add_url_rule("/api/2023-01/graphql",view_func=GraphQLView.as_view("graphql",schema=query_str,graphiql=True,),)
```

But I keep running into the following error:

> AssertionError: A Schema is required to be provided to GraphQLView.
> I am currently using:

- Flask="^2.0.1"
- Flask-Cors="^3.0.10"
- Flask-SQLAlchemy="^2.5.1"
- graphene="^2.1.9"
- Flask-GraphQL="^2.0.1"

I tried using the latest version of Flask-GraphQL but that had a conflict:

[image]

Any help or suggestions are welcome

PS: It works fine if I use a simple REST like POST request instead of app.add_url_rule

Edit:
Here is what query_str looks like:

> "mutation OrderCancellation { orderCancellation(orderId: 321,
> sku:"abc-123", input: { quantity:80 }) { order { orderId, sku,
> quantity } } }"

Comment: What is `schema=query_str` supposed to be doing? Seems there should be a schema there instead of a query string.

Comment: Sorry, I have added it to my question above. The query_str is just the string I get from a POST request. Am I not supposed to be using it as a string?